# A way to track a gas's expansion

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I was wondering if there is a way to see, empirically, how a gas behaves. Perhaps the most natural way is to use fumes with color, but they quickly disperse, rendering partially useless. Are there more modern methods, like introducing phosphorescent particles in the current or something of the kind?

Comment: By "expansion" here do you mean diffusion or mixing into an environment? If so, perhaps you should clarify the question a little.

Comment: @dmckee Either way. I would like to know if there are other ways to see how gases behave (mix, diffuse, flow, etc.)

Comment: The way your question is currently worded it could be mistaken for the wording of problems which occur in the elementary exposition of thermodynamics (in which a gas is isolated from it's environment but free to change it's volume subject only to it's equation of state). You might want to edit to make it clear that you are talking about a gas that can mix with it's environment.

Comment: "Fumes with color" do you mean using tracer particulate? There is no microscopic way to trace gas molecules experimentally. What you have already (using an advective scalar quantity (a tracer) is the best you can do, moreover, the rapid expansion and the diffusion you see is actually a good representation of what the bulk flow of the gas will do macroscopically.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a radioactive tracer gas.

Krypton-85 has been used to study atmospheric flow: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/JC075i015p02985/abstract

Otherwise, spectroscopic techniques such as absorbance or emission spectra could be used to measure the concentration of various gases at different points in space and time.